# Error encountered resolving symbol values statically

Tags: javascript, angular

In our Angular 2 app we have a build error, but only when using "ng build --prod", not when using "ng build" or "ng serve". The error message is:

```
ERROR in Error encountered resolving symbol values statically. Expression form not supported (position 27:55 in the original .ts file), resolving symbol RestService in [...]/src/app/shared-modules/service/rest/rest.service.ts

ERROR in ./src/main.ts
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve './$$_gendir/app/app.module.ngfactory' in 'C:\LPROG\Ldev\Projekte\svn\hippo_branch\frontend\shared\src'
 @ ./src/main.ts 5:0-74
 @ multi ./src/main.ts
```

The related code part is this:

```
    constructor(
      private http: Http,
      private mappingService: MappingService,
      private backendUrlService: BackendUrlService,
      @Inject('RestServiceConfig') public config: {rest_api_name: string}) {
```

I can change it to this:

```
    constructor(
      private http: Http,
      private mappingService: MappingService,
      private backendUrlService: BackendUrlService,
      @Inject('RestServiceConfig') public config: any) {
```

This works with "ng build --prod" and I think we can live with that change (though I still have other bugs, those shouldn't be related), but I wonder why that is and would like to have strong typing. Can somebody explain it to me?

```
ng -v
    _                      _                 ____ _     ___
   / \   _ __   __ _ _   _| | __ _ _ __     / ___| |   |_ _|
  / △ \ | '_ \ / _` | | | | |/ _` | '__|   | |   | |    | |
 / ___ \| | | | (_| | |_| | | (_| | |      | |___| |___ | |
/_/   \_\_| |_|\__, |\__,_|_|\__,_|_|       \____|_____|___|
               |___/
@angular/cli: 1.0.0-rc.1
node: 6.9.4
os: win32 x64
@angular/common: 2.4.10
@angular/compiler: 2.4.10
@angular/core: 2.4.10
@angular/forms: 2.4.10
@angular/http: 2.4.10
@angular/platform-browser: 2.4.10
@angular/platform-browser-dynamic: 2.4.10
@angular/router: 3.4.10
@angular/cli: 1.0.0-rc.1
@angular/compiler-cli: 2.4.10
```

Answer (score 0):

The reason you only get the error when you use `ng build --prod` is because that command implies the `--aot` switch as well.

Angular's [Ahead of Time](https://angular.io/guide/aot-compiler%20%22Ahead-of-Time%22%20compilation) compilation requires your code to be statically analyzable. The pay-off is a significant reduction in package size. I would suggest you change your code as follows, which gives you strong typing and working AOT. And a reusable type as well:

```
// Before your class
export interface Config {
  rest_api_name: string;
}

// In your class
constructor(
  private http: Http,
  private mappingService: MappingService,
  private backendUrlService: BackendUrlService,
  @Inject('RestServiceConfig') public config: Config) {
```

Comment: Sounds good to me. Unfortunately I have been moved to another project in the meantime and cannot verify. Is somebody else verifies it, let me know, so I can mark it as resolved.